# Project Reactor - How to create a sliding window Flux from a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, project-reactor

Java 8 Streams do not permit reuse. This creates a puzzle about how to reuse a stream when creating a sliding window flux to calculate a relationship like x(i)*x(i-1).

The following code is based on the idea of a shift operator. I shift the first stream with skip(1) to create a second stream.

```
Flux<Integer> primary = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed());
Flux<Integer> secondary = primary.skip(1);
primary.zipWith(secondary)
        .map(t -> t.getT1() * t.getT2())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Here is a visual representation of the above code:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
v v v v v v v v v v  skip(1)
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
v v v v v v v v v v  zipWith
1 2, 2 3, 3 4, 4 5, 5 6, 6 7, 7 8, 8 9, 9 10 <- sliding window of length 2
v v v v v v v v v v  multiples
2 6 12 20 30 42 56 72 90
```

Unfortunately this code errors as:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

The obvious work-around is to cache the elements and ensure the cache size is greater than or equal to the stream size:

```
Flux<Integer> primary = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed()).cache(10);
```

or use a stream replacement:

```
Flux<Integer> primary = Flux.range(0, 10);
```

The second solution will just re-execute the original sequence for the skip(1) sequence.

However an efficient solution only requires a buffer of size 2. This is a big deal if the stream happens to be a large file:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(megaFile));
```

How can I buffer a stream efficiently so multiple subscriptions to the primary Flux do not cause everything to be read into memory or cause re-executions?

Answer (score 5):

I finally discovered a solution although it is not buffer-oriented. The inspiration was to first solve the problem for a sliding window of 2:

```
Flux<Integer> primary = Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed());
primary.flatMap(num -> Flux.just(num, num))
    .skip(1)
    .buffer(2)
    .filter(list -> list.size() == 2)
    .map(list -> Arrays.toString(list.toArray()))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

A visual representation of the process follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
V V V V V V V V V    Flux.just(num, num)
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9
V V V V V V V V V    skip(1)
1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9
V V V V V V V V V    bufffer(2)
1 2, 2 3, 3 4, 4 5, 5 6, 6 7, 7 8, 8 9, 9
V V V V V V V V V    filter
1 2, 2 3, 3 4, 4 5, 5 6, 6 7, 7 8, 8 9
```

This is the output:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
[5, 6]
[6, 7]
[7, 8]
[8, 9]
```

Then I generalized the above idea to create a solution for an arbitrary sliding window size:

```
public class SlidingWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Different sliding windows for sequence 0 to 9:");
        SlidingWindow flux = new SlidingWindow();
        for (int windowSize = 1; windowSize < 5; windowSize++) {
            flux.slidingWindow(windowSize, IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed())
                .map(SlidingWindow::listToString)
                .subscribe(System.out::print);
            System.out.println();
        }

        //show stream difference: x(i)-x(i-1)
        List<Integer> sequence = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{10, 12, 11, 9, 13, 17, 21});
        System.out.println("Show difference 'x(i)-x(i-1)' for " + listToString(sequence));
        flux.slidingWindow(2, sequence.stream())
            .doOnNext(SlidingWindow::printlist)
            .map(list -> list.get(1) - list.get(0))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public <T> Flux<List<T>> slidingWindow(int windowSize, Stream<T> stream) {
        if (windowSize > 0) {
            Flux<List<T>> flux = Flux.fromStream(stream).map(ele -> Arrays.asList(ele));
            for (int i = 1; i < windowSize; i++) {
                flux = addDepth(flux);
            }
            return flux;
        } else {
            return Flux.empty();
        }
    }

    protected <T> Flux<List<T>> addDepth(Flux<List<T>> flux) {
        return flux.flatMap(list -> Flux.just(list, list))
            .skip(1)
            .buffer(2)
            .filter(list -> list.size() == 2)
            .map(list -> flatten(list));
    }

    protected <T> List<T> flatten(List<List<T>> list) {
        LinkedList<T> newl = new LinkedList<>(list.get(1));
        newl.addFirst(list.get(0).get(0));
        return newl;
    }

    static String listToString(List list) {
        return list.stream()
            .map(i -> i.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[ ", " ], "))
            .toString();
    }

    static void printlist(List list) {
        System.out.print(listToString(list));
    }

}
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

```
Different sliding windows for sequence 0 to 9:
[ 0 ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 6 ], [ 7 ], [ 8 ], [ 9 ], 
[ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 6, 7 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 8, 9 ], 
[ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ], [ 3, 4, 5 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 5, 6, 7 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ], 
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ], [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 6, 7, 8, 9 ], 

Show difference 'x(i)-x(i-1)' for [ 10, 12, 11, 9, 13, 17, 21 ], 
[ 10, 12 ], 2
[ 12, 11 ], -1
[ 11, 9 ], -2
[ 9, 13 ], 4
[ 13, 17 ], 4
[ 17, 21 ], 4
```

Comment: You can write

```primary.flatMap(num -> Flux.just(num, num)).skip(1).buffer(2)```

as 

```primary.buffer(2, 1)```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the following solution:

```java
public <T> Flux<Flux<T>> toSlidingWindow(Flux<T> source, int size) {
    return toSlidingWindow(source, deque -> {
        while (deque.size() > size) {
            deque.poll();
        }
        return Flux.fromIterable(deque);
    });
}

public <T> Flux<Flux<T>> toSlidingWindow(Flux<T> source, Function<Deque<T>, Flux<T>> dequePruneFunction) {
    return source.map(ohlc -> {
        Deque<T> deque = dequeAtomicReference.get();
        deque.offer(ohlc);
        return dequePruneFunction.apply(deque);
    });
}
```

This can either be a fixed size sliding window or use a custom function to determine the extent of each window.

If any multithreading problems arise using it like this you could copy the `Deque` within an `acquire` and `release` block which seems to be supported by `AtomicReference`. This would ensure the resulting window `Flux` to remain unchanged by other threads.

Perhaps like so:

```java
public <T> Flux<Flux<T>> toSlidingWindowAsync(Flux<T> source, int size) {
    return toSlidingWindowAsync(source, deque -> {
        while (deque.size() > size) {
            deque.poll();
        }
        return Flux.fromIterable(new LinkedList<>(deque));
    });
}

public <T> Flux<Flux<T>> toSlidingWindowAsync(Flux<T> source, Function<Deque<T>, Flux<T>> dequePruneFunction) {
    AtomicReference<Deque<T>> dequeAtomicReference = new AtomicReference<>(new LinkedList<>());
    return source.map(ohlc -> {
        Deque<T> deque = dequeAtomicReference.getAcquire();
        deque.offer(ohlc);
        Flux<T> windowFlux = dequePruneFunction.apply(deque);
        dequeAtomicReference.setRelease(deque);
        return windowFlux;
    });
}
```

This copies the `Deque` that is used for each resultant sliding window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactor Core 3 (I'm not sure when this operator was released), you can simply use

```
    Flux.fromStream(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed())
            .buffer(2, 1)
            .skipLast(1)
            .map(t -> t.stream().reduce((a, b)-> a*b))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The magic is the buffer(2, 1) part: here maxSize is 2, and skip is 1. Since maxSize is greater than skip, this creates overlapping buffers (that is, sliding windows) over the flux, and emits each buffer as a List.
The skipLast(1) is needed, as the last buffer will be a single element (of 10), this needs to be skipped.